Is this possible to subscribe to record change event in Google looker?
Is this possible to subscribe to record change event in Google looker?
Do such event exist in Google looker?
Is this possible to implement any hook to get some rest service called whenever record change happens?
I am not a Looker expert, neither my Mulesoft engineer. He suggested to pull data from Looker every 5 seconds from Mulesoft but this sounds to me like a terrible idea which may deteriorate performance of Looker application and I am looking for any better integration option rather than pull data from Looker every 5 seconds.
I bet there must be some solution which I can't find so far.
